# azimuth function produces different results depending on which unit is used

Tags: matlab, degrees, radians, azimuth

I am using the matlab function **`azimuth`** to calculate the angle between couples of points of coordinates (lon,lat) on an ellipsoid of characteristics [6378.1, 0.00335] (~ the Earth).

Surprisingly, asking for results in **radians** or **degrees** produces very different outputs. For instance, for the couple (106,35.5), (107,35) separated by 106.5925 km (cf first figure), the azimuth function returns **121.1881** degrees and 1.7571 radians, i.e. **100.6746** degrees, *which neither of them is right*.

[image]

On a statistical scale, this is what both outputs look like (distributions of angles in degrees and radians for about 19,000 couples of points):

[image: distributions of angles computed by azimuth function in both radians and degrees]

The output in radians has peaks in the North and South directions, while the output in degrees shows peaks in the four cardinal directions (which creates lows around those four cardinal directions).

I'm puzzled. Inputs have double precision, are (lon,lat) couples in the [0;360[ and [-90;90] ranges, respectively, nothing fancy. The ellipsoid used does not matter as long as its eccentricity is not zero.

Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: how are you calling the azimuth function? If you read the documentation, you can call the function and specify whether your inputs are in degrees or radians. Degrees is the default value.

Comment: I call it `angle = azimuth(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,ellipsoid,'units')` like the documentation provides, with 'units' being either 'radians' or 'degrees'

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to arise with `'rh'` as `TRACK` instead of the default `'gc'` value, which does not compute geodesic azimuths, but rather rhumb line azimuths (whatever those are, I just found it notable). Also: have you seen the warnings in the doc? As in "`Geodesic azimuths on an ellipsoid are valid only for small eccentricities typical of the Earth (e.g., 0.08 or less).`" (could be worse than they expect), and "`Azimuth calculations for geodesics degrade slowly with increasing distance and may break down for points that are nearly antipodal [...]`". Could this be related?

Comment: Well playing with these track options I found that 'rh' is not adapted...  

The distributions above are for distance of 8 to 830 km, with about half of that under 100 km... given the warning about distance in the doc and given that the eccentricity is 10 times smaller than the upper limit indicated, I don't know where to head.

Comment: Documentation says that that `distance` function also includes azimuth data; maybe that one is less buggy. Otherwise, I think you can submit bug report to MathWorks (it should have actual code reproducing the error, which, frankly speaking, you should have included here as well).

Comment: The azimuth output from `distance` has the same issues. I wonder if some of that is due to rounding errors.